# Docusign API - How to set expiration notification in Envelope (XML)

Tags: java, docusignapi

I need to set the expiration date for the document sent through API from docusign. I am user xml(not JSON) based request. I have been trying to achieve it with the below but havn't succeeded yet.

```
<notification>
   <expirations>
      <expireEnabled>true</expireEnabled>
      <expireAfter>1</expireAfter>
      <expireWarn>0</expireWarn>
   </expirations>
</notification>
```

Comment: Perhaps you need to specify both expiration and reminders if you do this at the envelope level. Perhaps try: <Notification>
        <Reminders>
                <ReminderEnabled>false</ReminderEnabled>
                <ReminderDelay>0</ReminderDelay>
                <ReminderFrequency>0</ReminderFrequency>
        </Reminders>
        <Expirations>
                <ExpireEnabled>true</ExpireEnabled>
                <ExpireAfter>120</ExpireAfter>
                <ExpireWarn>0</ExpireWarn>
        </Expirations>
</Notification>

Answer (score 1):

If you are still seeing this please share a little more of your request where you specify this in the envelope creation XML, and REST API endpoint. I just created an envelope using the REST API and XML. I used your notification block and it resulted in the following when querying the /notification endpoint for the envelope (in the notification block):

```
<expirations>
    <expireAfter>1</expireAfter>
    <expireEnabled>true</expireEnabled>
    <expireWarn>0</expireWarn>
</expirations>
<reminders>
    <reminderDelay>0</reminderDelay>
    <reminderEnabled>false</reminderEnabled>
    <reminderFrequency>0</reminderFrequency>
</reminders>
```